# List of possible events from event handler

Tags: openlayers, events, event-listener

This may be an elementary question but I cannot figure out how to word it so that I can google it properly.

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {
    var coordinates = evt.coordinate;
    alert(coordinates);
});
```

What I'm trying to find is the list of possibilities inside of "evt". i.e. - **evt.pixel**, **evt.coordinate**, **evt.dragging**, etc. Is there a list somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
});
```

Open up the developer console in your browser (`Ctrl+Shift+I` in firefox), go to the "Console" tab and expand the properties. Then you can explore every single part of the event for yourself.

Generic properties generated from a `click` event can be found at the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click).

Comment: When I did that, the list it gave me matched [the ones given here](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.MapBrowserEvent.html). Thanks for the help!